# Wifi network suddenly not visible anymore on certain device

Tags: windows-8.1, wifi-configuration

Since today, my laptop doesn't see my Wifi network anymore. My phone has no problems seeing it and connecting to it and other notebooks/phones around have no trouble either...
So I tested an external USB wifi device to search for my network, but still without any luck! My whole laptop just can't see it, even though I'm definitely in range.
And because of running downloads I can't restart the router for a day or so.

I fixed a million different Wifi and network problems in my life, but this weird issue is totally new to me.

Any idea what this could be caused by?

I'm on Windows 8.1 Pro x64 btw.

Comment: change your mac address and assign static ip to your network adapter, see if it fix the problem

Comment: I already tried a different wifi stick, which pretty much changes my mac. Why would setting a static ip help? The router is dhcp configured and a router could only see the ip of a device, once it's connected to it.

Comment: can u ping default gateway?

Comment: I am not connected to the network, how would I ping anything that way? not possible

Comment: I just booted linux on that PC and from there I can see it and connect to it without a problem.

Comment: try uninstall all devices related to network in device manager and refresh again

Comment: Not happening. I have like 6 virtual adaptors set up and I really don't want to mess up the bridges etc between these and my physical adaptors.

Comment: I scanned for wifi networks using inSSIDer and Cain. Still cant find it.

Comment: reset modem? lol

Comment: No there are a lot of important things going on atm. Maybe I can restart it in 2 days, but I really need to fix this issue now. I'm pretty sure this is a Windows issue because I could find the network just fine on Linux (same machine).

Comment: ya but still it can be modem issue. problem to provide service for windows device. not sure.

Comment: I don't think so. The router is obviously broadcasting. You can't just not broadcast to a specific device or even a specific OS. That's just not how it works.